# Navigation is not highlighting when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a script that dynamically generates table of contents but for some reason its not highlighting when scrolling. I am not sure why its not highlighting individual links as you scroll. Below is my jQuery script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toc").append(' ')
    $("h2").each(function(i) {
        var current = $(this);
        current.attr("id", "title" + i);
        $("#toc").append("<li>" + "<a id='link" + i + "' href='#title" + i + "' class='active'" + "' title='" + current.attr("tagName") + "'>" + current.html() + "</a>" + "</li>");

    });

});


$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('h2').each(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#toc toc a').removeClass('active');
            $('#toc toc a[href=#'+ id +']').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Here is a link to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dude12go8/138evyj0/4/

Comment: you have an error if you check the console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For attribute selector in jQuery you should use attribute followed by `$`.
Take a look at the doc [Jquery attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_end_value.asp)

I also made a change in the following block, Please check the snippet.

```
$('#toc li a').removeClass('active');
$('a[href$="'+id+'"]').addClass('active');
```

Also add `$('li:first-child').children().addClass('active');` at the end or `.each()` to add active class to the first item.

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#toc").append(' ')
 $("h2").each(function(i) {
  var current = $(this);
  current.attr("id", "title" + i);
  $("#toc").append(`<li><a id="link${i}" href="#title${i}"  title="${current.attr("tagName")}">${current.html()}</a></li>`);
 });
 $('li:first-child').children().addClass('active'); // Add this to add active class only on first item
});


$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('h2').each(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#toc li a').removeClass('active');
            $('a[href$="'+id+'"]').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
h2 {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
 color: #000;
 margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

#toc{
 color: #000;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0, 0, 0;
}

#toc li {
 margin: 1rem 0.2rem 0;
 color: #000;
}

#toc li a{
 color: #000;
 font-family: Calibri, Sans-sarif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
}

#toc li a:hover, #toc a.active {
 background: #666;
 color: #000;
}

.nav-container{
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 width: 160px;
 height: 180px;
 padding-top: 0px;
}

.container{
 margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>


<nav class="nav-container">

<ul id="toc"></ul>
</nav>


<div class="container">

<h2>Test1</h2>


<p>This is a test</p>
<p>This is a test</p>


<h2>Test2</h2>

<p>TLSDGn lsjdlgjsldj gljlsdjgljlsdjgljdsl gjldfjgljdfljgldjflkgj ldfjgljldfjgl jldfg</p>
<p>This is a test</p>
<p>This is a another test</p>
<p>This is a another another another test</p>

<h2>Test3</h2>


<p>This is a test</p>
<p>This is a test</p>


<h2>Test4</h2>

<p>TLSDGn lsjdlgjsldj gljlsdjgljlsdjgljdsl gjldfjgljdfljgldjflkgj ldfjgljldfjgl jldfg</p>
<p>This is a test</p>
<p>This is a another test</p>
<p>This is a another another another test</p>

<h2>Test5</h2>


<p>This is a test</p>
<p>This is a test</p>


<h2>Test6</h2>

<p>TLSDGn lsjdlgjsldj gljlsdjgljlsdjgljdsl gjldfjgljdfljgldjflkgj ldfjgljldfjgl jldfg</p>
<p>This is a test</p>
<p>This is a another test</p>
<p>This is a another another another test</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Akhil. Is there any reason why when clicking on Test2 link it stays as highlighted on Test1 link? when clicking on Test3 link it highlights Test2 link, etc.

Comment: Did you checked the snippet, I dont see such issue.  can you please elaborate the issue. Could you please mark it as correct answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: Ok it’s working but the navigation is not even displaying in IE.  Is this not supported in IE?

Comment: @user3683976 I dont have IE, I use linux. This should work in all browser, But I dont have a windows machine to check

Comment: I was able to figure it out! Thanks again for your help. Much appreciation